# Is it the end of the road for CiviCRM under Windows?

Tags: smarty, templates, windows

We run CiviCRM under Drupal and Windows/IIS. Having upgraded our test environment to 5.69.2, we found we could not register for events, as we got errors along the lines of:

```
unable to write file <Drupal Root>\web\sites\default\files\civicrm\templates_c\en_GB\2e\76\18\2e76180b35db0da6edad2430223cfbf8b09021fc_0.string.string:{eval var=$smartySingleUseString|smarty:nodefaults}.php
```

This is, I believe, due to characters such as : being illegal under Windows. I've been trying to discover where the file name is being generated. Using a regular expression to tidy up the file name before attempting to create it (rename a temporary file) around line 69 of <Drupal root>\vendor\civicrm\civicrm-packages\smarty3\vendor\smarty\smarty\libs\sysplugins\smarty_internal_runtime_writefile.php just gave other errors. I see the same issue when running a development environment under 5.71.alpha1.

So, is it time to move to Linux for all CiviCRM users?

Comment: Something similar was fixed at https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/28909. We just need to find where your line is. I'm thinking something to do with tokens.

Comment: If you change `fetch('string:` to `fetch('eval:` in this line does that fix it? https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/fbf738ed82313a0d6a3e5b873503244e82baf373/CRM/Utils/String.php#L1040

Comment: I tried turning off Smarty3 in civicrm_settings.php, and got an error along the lines of:

Civi\Crypto\Exception\CryptoException: Failed to find key by ID or tag (z6BNl0_wDYQft0x4mbQidOEKlHk) in <drupal root>\vendor\civicrm\civicrm-core\Civi\Crypto\CryptoToken.php on line 143

Comment: @Demerit I tried changing ```fetch('string``` to ```fetch('eval``` as suggested in ```<drupal root>\vendor\civicrm\civicrm-core\CRM\Utils\String.php``` line 1040 and got
```Civi\Crypto\Exception\CryptoException: Failed to find key by ID or tag (z6BNl0_wDYQft0x4mbQidOEKlHk) in \<drupal root>\vendor\civicrm\civicrm-core\Civi\Crypto\CryptoToken.php on line 143```

Comment: You might need to clear cache if you flip between smarty2 and smarty3? `cv flush`

Comment: Replacing string: with eval: in  line 1040 of ```<Drupal root>\vendor\civicrm\civicrm-core\CRM\Utils\String.php``` solves the file rename issue, but instead we have an issue with missing tokens. We get errors like:
```Civi\Crypto\Exception\CryptoException: Failed to find key by ID or tag (z6BNl0_wDYQft0x4mbQidOEKlHk) in D:\CiviCRM_Custom.git\drupal8\vendor\civicrm\civicrm-core\Civi\Crypto\CryptoToken.php on line 143```

The message seems to be missing a token.
The message is being created in the send function of:

```<Drupal root\vendor\civicrm\civicrm-core\CRM\Utils\Mail.php```

Comment: Do you have both [SIGN_KEYS](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/upgrade/version-specific/#signing-key) and [CRED_KEYS](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/upgrade/version-specific/#civicrm-534) defined in civicrm.settings.php? If not, see [quick fix](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/secret-keys/#quick-setup).

Comment: @Demerit Thanks, I had SIGN_KEYS and CRED_KEYS defined, but due to an earlier issue had them both starting with jwt, M when CRED_KEYS should have started with aes and sign keys with jwt. Making that correction solved the problem!

Answer (score 1):

Changing `string:` to `eval:` on line 1040 in `<drupal root>\vendor\civicrm\civicrm-core\CRM\Utils\String.php` and making sure CIVICRM_CRED_KEYS started with aes-cbk rather than jwt-hs256 solved the problem.

Comment: I am still getting errors when trying to register for an event. Fortunately on a test system., errors like:
```TypeError: Unsupported operand types: float + string in content_65b92792401997_13080208() (line 408 of D:\CiviCRM_Custom.git\drupal_test\vendor\civicrm\civicrm-packages\smarty3\vendor\smarty\smarty\libs\sysplugins\smarty_resource_recompiled.php(52) : eval()'d code).
```
I've tried debugging, but has anyone got a suggestion as to how you can discover the  content?

This has meant that we can't update our production environment and are considering moving off Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Just noting that this is patched in the latest CiviCRM release (5.69.5+) by @demerit with the fix he suggested above. In addition there was a separate issue relating to the text version of the offline event template - we now  ship 5.69.5 with a blank text version of the offline event template and we have removed almost all the text versions in 5.70  - if there is no blank version a text version is generated at the point of send from the rendered html.

However, people who have customised the text version will not automatically have their customised version updated - if you want to manually update rather than delete your text version there is discussion on the gitlab https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/4951 as to which lines specifically cause problems